# AWS Glue crawler change serde

Tags: aws-glue

I have csv's with quoted strings and the crawler by default registers the table with LazySimpleSerde.Is there anyway I can programmatically change this to use the OpenCSVSerde instead?

Comment: What do you mean programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of boto3 which is an aws sdk. You can simply call their api using python or any other language. To precisely answer your question - You will need to call update_table() api to update serde used by glue table.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.update_table

Comment: Unfortunately update_table() API requires all properties to be set for it to work. If you update just the serialization library, then it would nullify other properties. Is there a way to workaround this?